# Why do my imports work in pycharm, but not on the command line?

Tags: python, command-line, pycharm

I have the following folder layout:

```
my_folder/
    my_subfolder/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        import_1.py
        import_2.py
```

With files:

```
 # main.py
 from my_subfolder import import_1

 import_1.call_import_2(3)
```

And

```
 # import_1.py
 from my_subfolder import import_2

 def call_import_2(n):
     import_2.print_hello_world_n_times(n)
```

And

```
# import_2.py

def print_hello_world_n_times(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print('hello world')
```

Now the thing is, if I run `main.py` in pycharm, it works fine. However, if I run it from the command line `python my_subfolder/main.py` or `python main.py` (depending which folder I am in), it doesn't work! The git bash also cannot get it to work. I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError no module named 'my_subfolder'
```

Does anyone know what causes this discrepancy between pycharm and the command line?

Comment: try `from .my_subfolder import import_1`

Comment: @TenaciousB that doesn't work `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.my_package'; '__main__' is not a package`

Answer (score 0):

```
 # main.py
 from . import import_1

 import_1.call_import_2(3)
```

and

```
 # import_1.py
 from . import import_2

 def call_import_2(n):
     import_2.print_hello_world_n_times(n)
```

You're already in `my_subfolder` so it looks for another one inside of that.

Comment: That doesn't work for me `ImportError: cannot import name 'second_import' from '__main__'`

Comment: if you're running your script like a module `python -m <module_name>` then you need an `__main__.py`

Comment: @TenaciousB I'm really not sure what you exactly mean ':), could you spell it out for me?